# Java installation error in Ubuntu 18.4 LTS

Tags: java, django, oracle, java-8, crm

I have to run Django CRM in my local machine. I followed all commands and tried to install every dependency.

I got stuck in the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer -y java -version
```

I got the following error when I tried above command.

> E: Command line option 'e' [from -version] is not understood in combination with the other options.

The link of Github CRM [Django CRM](https://github.com/MicroPyramid/Django-CRM)

[Documentation](https://django-crm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup/index.html)

Please someone help me.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: That one is absolutely not working.

Comment: Why do you think you need Java to run Django?

Comment: then you are doing something absolutely wrong.

Comment: @Exprator sir. Did you checked the documentations.

Answer (score 1):

Looking to Django-CRM documentation, seems like the command to install java (required by elasticsearch dependency) it's not the correct one for ubuntu 18.04

To install it you need to run:

```
apt-get install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

Then you can follow the instructions as in the documentation

```
wget -qO - https://packages.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch > key.elastic
apt-key add key.elastic
echo "deb https://packages.elastic.co/elasticsearch/2.x/debian stable main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elasticsearch-2.x.list

apt-get update &&  apt-get install elasticsearch -y
```

Also, remember to add sudo on the commands if you are not running the commands as root